# Inverse Laplace transform of $\large \frac{1}{s^2-As^{1.5}}$

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

Title says it all.
How do I go about finding inverse Laplace transform of that expression?
If it were complete exponents, I would have used partial fractions. But what to do with non integer exponents?

Comment: Where did the expression come from? Did you perform a Laplace transform first, simplify and now need to do the inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: @JohnHabert: I am solving coupled partial differential equations(space and time) with a complicated boundary conditions. So, I solved it in Laplace domain and now I am trying to invert the solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{s^2-As^{1.5}} = -\frac{1}{A^3(\sqrt{s}+A)} + \frac{1}{A^3\sqrt{s}}-\frac{1}{A^2s}+\frac{1}{As^{1.5}}$$

The inverse Laplace transform of the first term doesn't have a closed form solution:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+Laplace+transform+1%2F%28sqrt%28s%29%2BA%29

The rest of the terms are easy.

Comment: erfc is considered a closed-form solution.  Can you derive it yourself?

Comment: I suppose it depends on your definition of closed-form solution. 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9199/what-does-closed-form-solution-usually-mean

Comment: I have a specific definition that says an expression is "closed-form" when there exists algorithms that allow one to compute that expression significantly faster to within machine precision than via a numerical integration.  For erf and erfc, this is absolutely the case.

Comment: Here is where I stated my definition of closed-form: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562769/what-would-qualify-as-a-valid-reason-to-believe-there-is-a-closed-form/562810#562810