# Favorite definite integral trick?

Tags: definite-integrals

I'm compiling a list of interesting definite integrals for an upcoming [blog post](http://nilknarf.langlab.org), and I thought that the math SE community might have a few interesting problems to offer. I am especially interested in integrals that use "tricks" that are hard to spot at first or are particularly elegant ways of solving seemingly difficult problems.

An example of such an integral is the following:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}dx$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2} 1-\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}dx$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2} 1-\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}dx$$
$$x\to \frac{\pi}{2}-x$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}dx$$
And so if one lets $I$ be the value of the integral,
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}-I$$
and
$$I=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
This integral holds a very good example of what an "integral trick" is, because it uses the properties of integrals to evaluate a very difficult-looking definite integral without *actually* evaluating it.

I look forward to seeing what everyone has to say!

Comment: Nice and useful, but I doubt that there is a general method to detect such a method (assuming it exists). The easiest integral I remember using such a trick is $\int cos(x)\cdot sin(x) dx$ and for the integrals $\int sin^2(x) dx$ or analogue $\int cos^2(x) dx$ it helps to use the property $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some users are mind bogglingly skilled at integration. How did they get there?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765198/some-users-are-mind-bogglingly-skilled-at-integration-how-did-they-get-there)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/lesser-known-integration-tricks